# Не могу понять тему курсовой работы

Tags: морфология, неологизмы

Что значит  формообразовательная модель неологизма? В гугле ничего толкового по этой теме нет.

Comment: Если это тема ***Вашей*** курсовой, то обратитесь к руководителю.

Comment: @shampar это всё-таки про английский язык... Вряд ли что-то толковое можно экстраполировать на русский.

Comment: http://vspu.ru/sites/default/files/disfiles/dissertations/dissertaciya._puchnina_a.s..pdf

Comment: И не может быть, потому что Вы термины перепутали. Нет формообразовательной модели слова, есть только словообразовательная. По этой теме материала много. Например,  http://cl.rushkolnik.ru/docs/8261/index-9628-21.html 
https://psibook.com/linguistics/slovoobrazovatelnye-neologizmy-v-sovremennom-russkom-i-horvatskom-yazykah.html